# CUDA __umul24 function, useful or not?

Tags: cuda, multiplication

Is worth replacing all multiplications with the __umul24 function in a CUDA kernel? I read different and opposite opinions and I can't still make a bechmark to figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only in devices with architecture prior to fermi, that is with cuda capabilities prior to 2.0 where the integer arithmetic unit is 24 bit.

On Cuda Device with capabilities >= 2.0 the architecture is 32 bit the _umul24 will be slower instead of faster. The reason is because it has to emulate the 24 bit operation with 32 bit architecture.

The question is now: Is it worth the effort for the speed gain ? Probably not.

Comment: I think is kind of bad advice... 

Your suggestion is valid IFF the programmer knows his target hardware will be CC>=2.0.  Otherwise, your solution will perform poorly in a heterogeneous CUDA device base, either in your own test machines or in your end users' machines.

Ask yourself, if you can accept inefficient code, why are you using CUDA in the first place?

It's really not hard, so I would NOT encourage taking this lazy road, just to save a bit of time and a bit of code length.

This kind of commentary leads to bad habits for beginners, teaching them to sell their performance short.

Comment: I would not put engineer effort in dealing with the __umul24 detail. As you might know ... premature optimization ...

Comment: I don't really see how copying and pasting a kernel and changing a handful of lines is "engineering effort".

My point is that there's other architectural differences, e.g. shared mem size, max # threads per block, etc.  So the op should be having their program query the CUDA compatibility and tailoring his thread calls, shared mem scheme to it.  If you already have gone that far, how bad is a measly copy and pasted kernel with a few lines changed?

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to chime in with a slightly different opinion than Ashwin/fabrizioM...

If you're just trying to teach yourself CUDA, their answer is probably more or less acceptable.  But if you're actually trying to deploy a production-grade app to a commercial or research setting, that sort of attitude is generally not acceptable, unless you are absolutely sure that your end users' (or you, if you're the end user) is Fermi or later.

More likely, there's many users who will be running CUDA on legacy machines who would receive benefits from using Compute Level appropriate functionality.  And it's not as hard as Ashwin/fabrizioM make it out to be.

e.g. in a code I'm working on, I'm using:

```
//For prior to Fermi use umul, for Fermi on, use
//native mult.
__device__ inline void MultiplyFermi(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{ a*b; }

__device__ inline void MultiplyAddFermi(unsigned int a, unsigned int b,
                                        unsigned int c)
{ a*b+c; }

__device__ inline void MultiplyOld(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{ __umul24(a,b); }

__device__ inline void MultiplyAddOld(unsigned int a, unsigned int b,
                                      unsigned int c)
{ __umul24(a,b)+c; }

//Maximum Occupancy =
//16384
void GetComputeCharacteristics(ComputeCapabilityLimits_t MyCapability)
{
    cudaDeviceProp DeviceProperties;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&DeviceProperties, 0 );
    MyCapability.ComputeCapability =
    double(DeviceProperties.major)+ double(DeviceProperties.minor)*0.1;
}
```

Now there IS a downside here.  What is it?

Well any kernel you use a multiplication, you must have two different versions of the kernel.

Is it worth it?

Well consider, this is a trivial copy & paste job, and you're gaining efficiency, yes in my opinion.  After all, CUDA isn't the easiest form of programming conceptually (nor is any parallel programming).  If performance is NOT critical, ask yourself: why are you using CUDA?

If performance is critical, it's negligent to to code lazy and either abandon legacy devices or post less-than-optimal execution, unless you're absolutely confident you can abandon legacy support for your deployment (allowing optimal execution).

For most, it makes sense to provide legacy support, given that it's not that hard once you realize how to do it.  Be aware this means that that you will also need to update your code, in order to adjust in to changes in future architectures.

Generally you should note what the latest version the code was targeted at, when it was written and perhaps print some sort of warning to users if they have a compute capability beyond what your latest implementation is optimized for.